# How to load 2 controllers one by one or at a time in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to load multiple controllers one by one or at a time. If yes  then Can anyone tell me how to load two different controllers at the time of loading page in AngularJs. I'm using routing.

Thank you.

Comment: controllers with angular2?

Comment: Sorry AngularJs not angular2

Comment: Is there even a concept of controllers in angular2.@Sajeetharan

Comment: @akash thats the same question i have posted

Comment: @Sam check the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can just refer them in the index.html in the order you want

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controller1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controller2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. My problem is I have login facility. Once user is logged in Username and password get stored in local storage. I have re-login method written in chatView controller. So that whenever I clear cache or refresh my page re-login can get automatically called. But in Map View I need to call both controller on page refresh so that my re-login get called.

Comment: you could handle that with the service

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong.You mean I should try call both controller using Service.

Comment: actually you dont need to call two controllers, you can just use the service to communicate

Comment: you got it sorted?

Comment: Thanks for your response.I'm trying to implement it using service.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from just referring them on index.html as @Sajeetharan suggested how about:

```
<ANY ng-controller="controller1 as ctrl1">
    <ANY ng-controller="controller2 as ctrl2">
        ....
    </ANY>
</ANY>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to solve this issue is wrong you can't control these things in a controller every time. Rather than calling both controllers you can use a service that will be doing this for you and you can call this service anytime you want in any controllers.

For your problem add this relogin to a service and call it whenever the controller loads in that way it will more feasible.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion . Let me create service then will get back to you all.